# How to return a struct with atomic member in C++

Tags: c++, stdatomic

Currently I have to work with legacy code and there is this struct:

```
typedef struct somesome {
  int val;
  std:atomic<int> index;
} somesome;
```

which is used inside this class:

```
class Blub {
protected:
  somesome blobb;
public:
  ...
  somesome getBlobb() const {return blobb;};
};
```

Because of the deleted copy constructor of atomic I can't return blobb, I believe...
How can I return blobb the right way?

Comment: Do you need to return a copy? Can you return by reference? You can make your own copy constructor though, which just sets the value appropriately.

Comment: Just implement your own or remove the `atomic`. In any case, watch out, because the author obviously didn't have a clue.

Comment: Why do you have an atomic member in there in the first place? It means the struct is used from multiple threads. Not a good idea to copy or move it! Maybe return a reference to it instead?

Comment: @rustyx @ulrich-eckhardt @chrismm yeah I don't know what the exact idea of my previous colleague was it seems though he was doing some kind of threading.. I just tried to compile the code and got stuck. Anyway I tried to add my own constructors like so:
`somesome() : val{0}, index{0} {} somesome(const somesome& data) : val{data.val}, index{data.index.load()} {}`

Comment: @rustyx copy is far better than a reference. mt read is np

Comment: @0xhph so you can't return it

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин what do you mean by mt read is no problem?

Comment: when several threads do read on same place in memory at the same time. So copy is better , but you really can't do it on this struct